# Matrix with one variable one to one and/or onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**
The linear transformation T=$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & k & 0\\
    0 & 0 & k^2\\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$ for $k>0$

(a) Is T one-to-one?

(b) Is T onto?

**Attempted answer:**

(a) T is one-to-one if $Tx=0$ has only trivial solutioni.e.
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & k & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & k^2 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1\\
    x_2 \\
    x_3 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
=   \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    0 \\
    0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Clearly $x_1$ = $x_2$ = $x_3$ = $0$ to obtain the zero vector as $k>0$, therefore $T$ is one-to-one.

(b) $T$ is onto if columns of $T$ span $P_2$.

$T$ has 3 linearly independent columns such that the vector space of $\alpha_0 + \alpha_1kx_1 + \alpha_2k^2x_2$ is $P_2$, therefore it is onto.

Comment: Your solution is correct

Answer (score 3):

A faster kill uses the Invertible Matrix Theorem. We have that the linear mapping $T$ is invertible (one-to-one and onto) iff its determinant is nonzero, or if zero is not an eigenvalue of $T$.

This is easy here. As $k$ is nonzero, the matrix representing $T$ as nonzero determinant (the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal elements), and hence zero is not an eigenvalue. Therefore $T$ is one-to-one and onto.